# Python crawler which than sends out results via email

Tags: python, email, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, reddit

thanks for helping.
So I tried to make a little crawler which checks out the gif page of reddit, than writes down all the gifs + titles, puts them in a list and than sends this list via email *(to my work colleagues)*.

So far so good, works perfectly, BUT the list it send looks like this
e.g:

> '1. Old man dancing at electronic music festival: http://i.imgur.com/2EtphXY.gifv', '2. Generation text..: http://i.imgur.com/fH6eV2B.gifv', '3. Porcupine climbs up for warmth:

etc...

**What do I want?** I want that the titles + links are printed by single row in the email + i wanne add a text to it. 
like this

> Hello friends welcome to daily gifs
>
> 1. title1: link1
> 2. title2: link2
> 3. title3: link3

This is my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import smtplib
import time
import random
import datetime

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/?count=26&before=t3_3u4mnz'
response = opener.open(url)
page = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
list = []

variable = 1
for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'title may-blank '}):
    href = link.get('href')
    name = link.string
    #print str(variable) + ". " + name + " : " + href
    list.append(str(str(variable) + ". " + name + ": " + href))
    variable += 1


GMAIL_USERNAME = "blabla@blabla.com"
GMAIL_PASSWORD  = "xxxxxxxx"
email_subject = "Lunchtime gifs of the day: " + str(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
recipient = "workfriends@blabla.com"
body_of_email = str(list)[1:-1]
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
session.ehlo()
session.starttls()
session.login(GMAIL_USERNAME, GMAIL_PASSWORD)

headers = "\r\n".join(["from: " + GMAIL_USERNAME,
                       "subject: " + email_subject,
                       "to: " + recipient,
                       "mime-version: 1.0",
                       "content-type: text/html"])

content = headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body_of_email

session.sendmail(GMAIL_USERNAME, recipient, content)

print "Email send!"
```

Comment: Just put <br> at the end of each line. Or you could probably put them in between an <ol></ol> tags as <Li> and let the html engine number them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An email's content type is determined using the `Content-Type` header. You've specified that that content type for your email is `text/html` and clients that read this email will interpret the bits as HTML.

So, make the bits that you're sending look like HTML. I would use `<br />` or `<ol />` `<li />` tags. Alternatively, send the email as `text/plain` and your `\n` characters will be interpreted as you would expect.

Personally, for emails like this, I prefer for them to be in `text/plain` format.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this line in your for loop.

```
    list.append(str(str(variable) + ". " + name + ": " + href+"\n"))
```

This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail):

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP('gmail_username', 'gmail_password')
yag.send('to@email.com', 'subjectline', contents='content')
```

Note that content will be put into HTML. So you could literally also just put stuff like:

```
contents = ['<h1>title1</h1><a href="link1">link1</a>',
            '<h1>title2</h1><a href="link2">link2</a>'
```

etc.

Get your copy of yagmail using `pip install yagmail`.

Full disclosure: I'm the developer of yagmail.